# How to restore my ec2 instance with rds snapshot

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, rds

I am very new in amazon aws. I have one instance in Singapore region and site is developed in magneto. Database connection is with RDS. My site become offline after flush in magneto with following error - Error log record number: 1458881500905

```
enter code here : 
a:4:{i:0;s:109:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)";i:1;s:2213:"#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I have try to restore website with old instance but its not coming.
Due to flush my database affected? or should I restore it with old snapshot of rds.
Also how to restore old snapshot with existing ec2.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS RDS Dashboard, restore snapshots to bringing up DB instance. In DB Instance security group, open MySQL port for your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Done : site live by sql restart:
sudo `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

But still want to know how to restore rds snapshot and connect to existing instance

Comment: If you solved this with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` then this suggests you are almost certainly **not** using an RDS database.

Comment: As mentioned by @Michael-sqlbot , you are using a local database instead of RDS. Or you install RDS, but didn't point it to RDS properly.

Comment: It is connected with rds only as we have set rds credential in local.xml of magento database configration. I have first restart apache but its not work. Yes there is no connection between SQL restart as we connected through RDS. But after restarting SQl, site live.